# Simple NodeJS http request equivalent for curl

Tags: node.js, curl

I'm having trouble converting a curl that works to an equivalent http request through nodeJS. I'm using the Request module, but I seem to be doing something wrong when making the request. When I run it, it gives me

```
body: Cannot POST /path
```

Not really sure how to debug this, any ideas?

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  'sender': {
    'name': 'name',
    'handle': 'handle'
  }, 
  'subject': 'Title here',
  'body': 'something something',
  'metadata': {}
});

var options = {
    host: 'website.com',
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});
req.write(data);
req.end();
```

Below is the equivalent curl (that works) that I'm trying to make for the above nodejs.

```
curl --include \
    --request POST \
    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --data-binary "{
    \"sender\": {
       \"name\": \"name\",
       \"handle\": \"handle\"
    },
    \"subject\": \"Title here\",
    \"body\": \"something something\",
    \"metadata\": {}
    }" \
    'website.com/path"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your JSON data directly with `json` parameter with [request](https://github.com/request/request) library :

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    uri: 'http://website.com/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    json: {
        'sender': {
            'name': 'name',
            'handle': 'handle'
        },
        'subject': 'Title here',
        'body': 'something something',
        'metadata': {}
    }
};

var req = request(options, function(error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } else {
        console.log("receive status code : " + response.statusCode);
    }
});
```

From [request options doc](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) :

> json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds
>   Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the
>   response body as JSON.

Comment: thank you! I had trouble understanding the docs and looked for examples, but this seemed to clarify it. I thought data had to be sent after defining the request

Comment: Glad it helped, you can accept the answer if it's good for you